# The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try...... - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, crash, crashlytics

Once i enter the phone number and otp its not moving to the next screen and Its giving a error toast msg as sms code has expired, please resend the verification code.But once i close the app and re-open it its moving to the next screen. I've checked crashlytics for errors but there are no errors displayed in that to. The app is working perfectly fine in emulator and when i download the app through the release apk generated but this error is shown only when the app is uploaded to playstore and downloaded from the playstore. Its also working fine on redmi device but its showing the error in samsung and oneplus device.

This is the phone number screen code

```
 onPressed: () async {
                    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                      phoneNumber: countrycode.text + phone,
                      timeout: const Duration(minutes:2),
                      verificationCompleted:
                          (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
                        await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .signInWithCredential(credential);
                      },
                      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
                        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg: "The provided phone number is not valid.",
                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          );
                        } else {
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg: e.message!,
                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
                        MyPhone.verify = verificationId;

                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => MyOtp(
                              verificationID: verificationId,
                              resendToken: resendToken,
                              phoneNumber: countrycode.text + phone,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
                    );
                  },
```

This is the otp screen code

```
 Future<void> verifyOtp(String verificationId, String verificationCode,
      BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithCredential(
        PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: verificationId,
          smsCode: verificationCode,
        ),
      );
      firestore.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).get().then(
            (doc) => {
              if (doc.exists)
                {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const MyBp(),
                    ),
                  ),
                }
              else
                {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const MyRegister(),
                    ),
                  ),
                }
            },
          );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.message.toString());
    }
  }
```

Need help with this.

I tried looking for crashes in crashlytics but it was not showing any crashes. I am looking for solutions.